# How can i identify and remove jsonObject empty properties without using for each

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**My requirement is**,

> By default submit button is in disable mode, If user changes existing
>   data in form then submit button should change to enable mode after
>   that he changes his mind and reverted back to old data then submit
>   button should change to disable mode.

For this requirement I have done code changes those are

1. While loading form data I am taking a temporary variable placing
   form data in that temporary variable.
2. User changes any field in the form I am comparing form data with that temporary form data by using `angular.equals(obj, tempObj)`
   method.

These code changes are working for one way i.e, User changes form data, I am identifying that event and comparing form data with temporary data and changing the button into enable mode --> working

**The problem** is my form contains non mandatory fields. By default form contains empty data in those non mandatory fields.

First user enters data in that non mandatory field then one json key, value pair is creating in my JsonObject. When i compare two objects by using equals method it is returning false after that i revert back that non mandatory field but the created json object property is not removing from JsonObject with empty value. This is angular inbuilt behavior.

Can anyone suggest me how to remove that empty value json key in my JsonObject.

**Note :** I will not use for each to iterate and find the empty json value and remove it from the JsonObject because my form contains 40 elements. It will leads the performance of my application. I have to apply same behavior in different places.

Comment: 40 elements is *nothing*. Go ahead and use `forEach`. If you had 10000 or more, you might start to worry, but do a performance test first to prove that it's a problem before thinking about refactoring code around it.

Comment: 1. Please add reproducible code of your problem. 2. Iterating over 40 objects will not cause performance issues

Comment: I think you may be confused as to what JSON is. JSON can not have "empty value" in the first place. Are you *actually* dealing with a javascript object which you later "stringify" to JSON?

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs Use this library to filter out your data this is very lite and algorithms are very optimized.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Do we have any approach to stop assigning empty json property to JsonObject, when user revert back the entered value in Non mandatory input field.

Answer (score 0):

You can _.Omit to remove json object https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#omit